# How to set up a 6to4 tunnel on windows

Tags: windows, networking, ipv6, tunnel, 6to4

There are 6to4 tunnel services like http://tb.netassist.ua/ or https://tunnelbroker.net/ but how can i set up those on windows?

if I run the script (for example from netassist):

```
netsh interface teredo set state disabled
netsh interface ipv6 add v6v4tunnel *Client IPv4 address* *Server IPv4 address*
netsh interface ipv6 add address IP6Tunnel *Client IPv6 address*
netsh interface ipv6 add route ::/0 IP6Tunnel *Server IPv6 address*
```

https://test-ipv6.com/ still detectes no ipv6 address.
Sry if this is a dump question but i am a noob in networking stuff like this.

Comment: Is the machine behind a NAT? Are you specifying its private or public IPv4 address in the first command? What results do you get from trying to `ping` an IPv6 address?

Comment: yes the machine is behind a NAT and i only want to set up the tunnel for my device, so i dont want to set it up on the router. If i ping "ping -6 ipv6.google.com" i get "General failure"

Comment: Those are 6in4 tunnel services. That is something else than 6to4. Don't confuse the two of them. 6in4 will only work behind NAT if you forward Protocol 41 (not port 41!) to your machine where you set up the tunnel.

Comment: @TJJ: They're practically the same thing. "6to4" is exactly the same Protocol 41 as 6in4, only with an anycast endpoint.